# Apple developer rejects my application in Test Flight

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

After pushing the application to test flight, I added a MobileTest Developer to check the app in test flight, but the application has been rejected in the Apple store.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It hasn't been rejected for the App Store; You haven't even submitted it to the App Store.  It was rejected for TestFlight, which probably means your app crashed on launch or something equally bad; TestFlight review has a lot of tolerance but your app has to at least *run*.  They would have sent you an email about the rejection. As an internal tester you can also download your app and see what's up with it

Comment: It could also be the default Flutter icon

Answer (score 0):

You can check the reason for the rejection in the apple developer account's Email.
and also you can publish it as internal **"Internal Testing"**, which doesn't require approval from Apple.
Internal testing doesn't check from Apple.

[image]